# How to print a log from text file(saved in my phone) to cmd prompt

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

When my scenario gets failed in uiAutomator, i want to print the exception/failure logs in cmd prompt from the logcat log.How to achieve this?

(Below code prints the current log)

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -e").getInputStream()));
              String data;    
                      while((data = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)   
              {                                        
              System.out.println(data);
              }
              }
```

Comment: Why don't you use try/catch blocks with assert statements for checks

Answer (score 0):

The actual command to be used is

**logcat *:E**

This will print the error logs of the device on to the command prompt. Please update you code in this way.

```
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d *:E")
                            .getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this project [Uiautomator-bot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/). It collects logs while each test case is running. It can execute test cases on more than one device simultaneously. Further, you don't have to write any code to save logs. For more information check this [link](http://uiautomator-bot.blogspot.in/)